# How to generate exception in WebBrowser control window.external method implemented in MFC?

Tags: javascript, c++, mfc, browser

I use WebBrowser control and MFC HTML dialog to build portable C++ application interface. I use window.external (which is actually my dialog class) to expose C++ functionality for JavaScript code inside browser. So, for example, when user wants to save settings, he clicks Save button, and in this event I call window.external like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Save").click(function() {
try
{
   window.external.Save();
}
catch(error)
{
   alert(error);
});
</script>
```

Now, in HTML dialog I have method like this:

```
void CMyDialog::Save()
{
   // Do something...
}
```

If user entered invalid settings, it looks logical to generate exception within CMyDialog::Save() to stop method execution and show any error message. However, the problem here is that C++ exception must be processed by JavaScript, and I have no idea how to implement it.
So: **is there any way to throw exception in C++ code in such a way that JavaScript will can handle it with its try-catch statement?**
P. S. I understand that there are ways to avoid this problem, for example, it is possible to return error code from Save method instead of throwing exceptions and return 0 on success, etc; however, exceptions are much more comfortable & intuitive way to report error at least for me, so if someone knows solution, please write your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ code you indicate error by returning `HRESULT` values showing failure (negative ones). Those alone will already be converted to scripting exceptions ([Error Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dww52sbt%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)).

If you want to provide extended information, such as message, you can implement [`ISupportErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface on your C++ class which implements `IDispatch`/`IDispatchEx` interface, and return error information as described in this topic on MSDN: [Returning Error Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).